# For Rasa core and Rasa nlu, how should a reliable infrastructure?

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

My REST application is being developed with Python and Flask, I am also using Rasa Core and Rasa NLU. Currently everything is a single local development server. Would you like to know what ideal recommendations for production?

A scenario that I imagined: treat all REST flames and database structure on one server, keep Rasa Core and together with a "micro" python application on another server and Rasa NLU on a third server.

But the question is: all users would end up asking the 3 cascading servers, so I think all servers are subject to the same bottleneck of requests.

---

And what would be the ideal settings if you leave 1 server with all or 3 servers? (for AWS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be the most scale-able you can use a containerized solution with load balancing.

1. Rasa NLU has a public docker container (or you could create your
   own). Use docker & kubernetes to scale out the NLU to however large 
   you need your base
2. Create separate docker containers for your rasa core, connecting to the NLU load balancer for NLU translation.  Use a load balancer here too if you need to.
3. Do the same for your REST application, connecting to #2 load balancer

This solution would allow you to scale your NLU and core separately however you need to as well as your REST application if you need to do that separately.

I wrote a tutorial on this if you are interested [here](http://smithstrategy.com/index.php/2018/02/28/chatbot-tutorial-using-rasa-and-docker/):